# underfined reference помогите

Tags: c, header

```
||=== Build: Debug in Lab11 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
  obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
   C:\Users\enter\Desktop\Code\C++\Lab11\main.c|8|undefined reference to `create'|
   C:\Users\enter\Desktop\Code\C++\Lab11\main.c|9|undefined reference to `perimetr'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

## main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pentagon.h"

int main()
{
    struct data d;
    d = create(d);
    printf("%d" , perimetr(d));
    return 0;
}
```

## pentagon.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pentagon.h"

struct data create(struct data pent)
{
    scanf("%d" , &pent.storona);
    return pent;
}

int perimetr(struct data pent)
{
    return pent.storona * 5;
}
```

## pentagon.h

```
#ifndef PENTAGON_H_INCLUDED
#define PENTAGON_H_INCLUDED

struct data
{
    int storona;
};

struct data create(struct data pent);

int perimetr(struct data pent);

#endif // PENTAGON_H_INCLUDED
```

Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема. Чем подробнее тем лучше.

Comment: Возможно, в компиляторе не линкуется заголовочный файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функции `create` и `perimetr` вы реализовали в `pentagon.c`, но компилятору об этом сказать забыли. Файл `pentagon.c` компилятору и/или линкеру совершенно не известен. Поэтому он и не может найти определения этих функций.

Comment: На всякий случай, можно посмотреть примеры параметров компиляции для gcc на англоязычном сообществе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998485/in-c-programming-what-is-undefined-referenceerror-when-compiling